# R - Print record in console like PSQL

Tags: r

Is there a way to print a record from a table in R console looking like PSQL with \x enabled? Meaning print it on the vertical?

Something like this:

```
-Record1-
Var1 | xxx
Var2 | yyy
Var3 | zzz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kable` from `knitr` will help you!

```
> df1
  E     F         G         H
1 A 0.9,1                    
2 B       0.98,0.34 0.98,0.34
3 C                          
> knitr::kable(df1)


|E  |F     |G         |H         |
|:--|:-----|:---------|:---------|
|A  |0.9,1 |          |          |
|B  |      |0.98,0.34 |0.98,0.34 |
|C  |      |          |          |
>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `gather` the dataset using the `tidyr` package, it will basically be stored in that format.

If the original looks like..

```
        Var1  Var2  Var3   
Record1 xxx   yyy   xxx
```

The gathered dataset will look like...

```
Record1 Var1 xxx
Record1 Var2 yyy
Record1 Var3 zzz
```

Or perhaps even using `str(YourData[x,])` will be sufficient if just for a quick check of a single record without needing to restructure the dataset.

Or, if you're set on the style in your example, this function is one (rough) way to approach it:

```
vertical_print_function <- function(data_vert,console=T){
psql <- character()
for(i in 1:nrow(data_vert)){
  psql <- append(psql,paste0("\n\n-Record ",i,"-"))
  colnames_s <- colnames(data_vert)
  var_names <- colnames_s %>% stringr::str_pad(width=max(nchar(.)))
    for(x in 1:ncol(data_vert)){
      psql <- append(psql,paste0("\n",var_names[x],"  |  ",data_vert[i,colnames_s[x]]))
  }
} 
if (console==T) {
  cat(psql)
  } else {
    return(psql)
  }
}
```

`console` as `TRUE` prints immediately to the console (dangerous/pointless if many records). `FALSE` just returns the string, which can then exported to a text file.